# update depended observable in computed observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need update observable value (filter) in computed observable after ajax request (async ajax request), but computed observable (filterChanged) depend to this observable (filter) when I update observable in computed, an infinite loop occured in computed?

How can i update depended observable in computed observable?

```
function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.filter = ko.observable();
    self.isOpenFilter = ko.observable(false);

    self.result = ko.obseravableArray([]);

    self.filterChanged = ko.computed(function(){
            var data = {filter:self.filter(),isOpen:self.isOpenFilter()}


        $.ajax("/service",data,function(response){
            self.result(ko.mappings.fromJS(response.results);
            self.filter(response.filter);   // infinite loop
                    self.isOpenFilter(response.isOpen);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: to use a computed like this is strange, use subscribe instead, since you update filter you need to handle the infinite loop from your code

Comment: I have 10-15 observable like filter, I want to use computed for handle all of changes without write subscribe to each of observable

Comment: ok, but the fact remains, you need to handle the infinite recursion

Comment: You have to write stop condition. i.e.
if(response.filter != self.filter()) self.filter(response.filter)

this should help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using `ko.computed`. Something like this makes more sense:

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.filter = ko.observable("default filter");
    self.result = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.updateFilter = function() {
        var filter = self.filter();

        $.ajax("/service",
               {filter:filter},
               function(response){
                   self.result(ko.mappings.fromJS(response.results));
                   self.filter(response.filter);
               });
    };
}
```

If you call `updateFilter` to get an update from the server, it will change the `filter` computed property and if your View is bound to that property it should update automatically.

For an example, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDFHn/2/).

Comment: I need auto update filter when ui filter changed, I use ko.computed for this reason, I have many depended observable like filter

Comment: I can't trigger updateFilter using a button or somethink, it must be trigger automatically

Comment: subscribe to the filter and call the ajax from there. THat will give infinite loop too. You need to handle that in your code